# Відкритий цифровий англо-український словник

Tags: from-english, resource-request

Які існують якісні англо-українські словники у вигляді веб-сервісів, або програмних застосунків, для безкоштовного комерційного використання? Він мені потрібен для інтегрування в онлайн-сервіс для вивчення мов, тому важлива безкоштовність, а також формат з яким можна працювати програмними засобами.

Я зустрічав лише [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hello#Translations), де для англійського слова в розділі `Translations` можна знайти переклади на інші мови, в тому числі на українську. Проте, користуватись ним для пошуку перекладу не дуже зручно, та й перевести його в формат зручний для автоматизації досить складно.

Можливо є інші варіанти?

Comment: Як щодо https://translate.google.com.ua/#en/uk/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спробуйте [Glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/)

У них є безкоштовне [API](https://uk.glosbe.com/a-api)

Але памʼятайте, що наповнюється словник практично безконтрольно всіма бажаючими, модерація дуже слабка або взагалі відсутня. Отже спочатку перевірте, чи влаштує вас якість перекладів.

З офіційного опису:

> Glosbe - багатомовний онлайн словник
>
> Ми надаємо безкоштовні словники для майже кожної існуючої мови та
>   памяті перекладів з 1013284995 пропозицій.
>
> Майже кожна жива мова. Величезна база даних словника. Мільйони
>   прикладів. Унікальні фрази і вирази. Якщо ваша мова не перерахована у
>   окремих боксах, спробуйте переглянути всі словники.

Comment: Дякую. Це дійсно хороший ресурс з цілком прийнятною якістю перекладів.

Comment: Якщо можна, додайте хоча-б один-два рядки описання запропонованого ресурсу, аби ваша відповідь була self-sustainable.

Answer (score 6):

Я знаю доволі непоганий сайт як:

http://e2u.org.ua/

Сподіваюсь, підійде.

Даний ресурс включає [наступні словники:](https://e2u.org.ua/main/dicts)

- Загальний народний англійсько-український словник
- Фразлекс (англо-український фразеологічний словник)
- Довідник англійських, німецьких та українських ідіом і виразів
- Англійсько-український словник сучасних термінів з ІТ
- Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики
- Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська
- Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина ІІ українсько-англійська
- Англійсько-французько-німецько-український словник термінології  Європейського Союзу “Лабораторія наукового перекладу”
- Українсько-англійський словник
- Українсько-англійський словник з прав людини
- Українсько-англійський словник лінгвістичної термінології

Comment: Так, вчора також на нього натрапив. Я не знайшов там можливості скачати цей словник у вигляді якогось файлу, щоб можна було використовувати в програмному забезпеченні, але як онлайн сервіс для особистого користування дійсно дуже хороший.

Comment: @BartoNaz Якщо вам потрібен файл словника, то спробуйте запитати у них на форумі. Мені вони колись дали файл з лексемами української мови.

Comment: До вас також прохання. Якщо можна, додайте хоча-б один-два рядки описання запропонованого ресурсу, аби ваша відповідь була self-sustainable.

Comment: Сподіваюсь, так влаштує.

Answer (score 3):

Вас можуть зацікавити ці файли: https://sourceforge.net/projects/linguisto/files/en_uk/ Тут англо-український словник у форматі xdxf.

Вкрай сумніваюся, що цей словник справді вільний, бо "За основу взято Англо-український словник : близько 120000 слів: У 2 т. / склав М. І. Балла. - К. : Освіта, 1996." (http://linguisto.eu/dict/en;jsessionid=ZSV-XKUjWpInP3SkJGbb2JZ8.pm-linguisto.rhcloud.com).

Але для програмних засобів це найзручніше, що я знайшов.